# HTML, divs are not floating left

Tags: html, css-float

My divs simply wont float left, they line up vertically one the screen. I want them to be right next to each other. I have a feeling the max-width stuff isn't working. I had this working at one point but not anymore apparently.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TV Shows</title>

<style type="text/css">
    .coverGroup {
    display: block;
    max-width: 297px;
    height: 179px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .coverImage img {
    border:5px solid #ddd;
    }
    .coverImage:hover img {
    border: 5px solid #555; 
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<span style="font-size:20px;">Click on the show of your choice</span>
<br /> 

<div class="coverImage">
    <a href="/1/american-dad!" title="American Dad!">
        <img height="179" width="287" src="/1/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Episodes1.png"/>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="coverImage">
  <a href="/1/family-guy" title="Family Guy">
  <img height="179"  width="287" src="/1/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/500px-Family_Guy_Logo.svg1_-300x179.png"/>
    </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you use the class .coverGroup in the HTML?????

Answer (score 2):

You forgot using the correct class for the divs.
The class coverGroup has the floating attribute, but you use coverImage.

You could do it like:

```
<div class="coverImage coverGroup">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<div class="coverImage coverGroup">
```

instead of

```
<div class="coverImage">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the styles applied to the .coverGroup class, but that class isn't used anywhere in the code. If you rename .coverGroup to .coverImage that will work.